# Unable to catch NoSuchElementException in user code

Tags: c#, selenium, findelement

Even though my code is enclosed in a try block, I am still getting an unhandled exception,
"An exception of type OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code.

Here is the code:

```
        try
        {

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));

            switch (findBy)
            {
                case SeleniumFindBy.ById:
                    itemtext = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id(elementId)).Text);
                    break;

                case SeleniumFindBy.ByName:
                    itemtext = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Name(elementId)).Text);
                    break;

                case SeleniumFindBy.ByLinkText:
                    itemtext = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.LinkText(elementId)).Text);
                    break;

                case SeleniumFindBy.ByPartialLinkText:
                    itemtext = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText(elementId)).Text);
                    break;

                case SeleniumFindBy.ByXPath:
                    itemtext = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath(elementId)).Text);
                    break;

                case SeleniumFindBy.CssSelector:
                    itemtext = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.CssSelector(elementId)).Text);
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException ex)
        {
            LastError = elementId + "," + ex.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LastError = elementId + "," + ex.Message;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you are using lambda expression as:

```
itemtext = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id(elementId)).Text);
```

The lambda expression still relies on [`FindElement()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_ISearchContext_FindElement.htm) method.

---

### FindElement Method

*ISearchContext.FindElement Method* finds the first [IWebElement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement.htm) using the given method.

Syntax:

```
IWebElement FindElement(
    By by
)
```

Return Value

```
Type: IWebElement
The first matching IWebElement on the current context.
```

Exception: [NoSuchElementException](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_NoSuchElementException.htm)

---

### This usecase

As the inner `FindElement Method()` fails, hence you see *NoSuchElementException*.

### Solution

As a solution you can handle the exception that gets thrown when the element is not found within a `try-catch{}` block as follows:

```
itemtext = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
{
    try
    {
        return d.FindElement(By.Id(elementId).Text);
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
});
break;
```